# WPF Dispatcher and Running it in background

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I tried to wrap the dispatcher in a thread. But the result is not what i expect. How can i solve that problem?

```
    public void Start()
    {
        ThreadStart ts = inner;
        Thread wrapper = new Thread(ts);
        wrapper.Start();
    }

    private void inner()
    {
        _Runner.Dispatcher.Invoke(_Runner.Action, DispatcherPriority.Normal);
    }
```

Comment: What is the result and what you expect

Comment: Expectation : Dispatcher and Running it in background

also tried BeginInvoke. Result is same. When start called from client (click button etc.) thread's running and ending. But the client can not do anything while the process is running.

Answer (score 5):

You have not shown us enough code/explained yourself well enough to be able to provide a good answer, but I'm *guessing* your action (`_Runner.Action`) is expensive and slow to execute. If so, that is why your UI is unresponsive. You're essentially telling the Dispatcher to run that expensive operation on the UI thread when what you really want to do is run as much of your operation on the background thread as possible, and then marshal back to the UI thread via the `Dispatcher` only when necessary.

Comment: The background thread does not help if it immediately calls the dispatcher to execute the task on the UI thread.

Answer (score 2):

When you fire an action through/on the dispatcher, that action is called on the UI thread.

My guess is that you are doing the work/processing in the `_Runner.Action` function and it is tying up the UI thread. You'll have to do the main processing part in the `inner()` function and then call the Dispatcher for the final update details.

If you absolutely must process on the dispatcher, break your process into smaller pieces and call Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() for each piece so other events can be processed in between your process.

Answer (score 2):

You need to break Runner.Action into two parts - the long running part that does the calculation and the part that updates the GUI.

After you do that you call the long running part in the background thread and use the dispatcher only on the UI update part.

By the way, you should also probably use BeginInvoke and not Invoke.

If the long running part of Runner.Action is updating the GUI than you can't use a background thread to solve your problem - there are solutions for slow GUI operations but they change depending on what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that will let you run WPF applications with multiple UI threads. I believe this will help you. Refer to this http://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/running-wpf-application-with-multiple-ui-threads/

```
Thread lThread = new Thread(() =>
                   {
                        var lWnd = new Window1();
                        lWnd.Show();
                        lWnd.Closed += (sender2, e2) => lWnd.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
                        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
                   });
lThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
lThread.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ditto what everyone here has said.

Additionally, you may want to look into using the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have started using for background tasks... I have not been using it long, so I don't know if there are bugs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SSA.Utility
{
    public class BackgroundTaskManager : IDisposable
    {
        private System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher _OwnerDispatcher;
        private System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher _WorkerDispatcher;
        private System.Threading.Thread _WorkerThread;
        private Boolean _WorkerBusy;

        private System.Threading.EventWaitHandle _WorkerStarted = new System.Threading.EventWaitHandle(false, System.Threading.EventResetMode.ManualReset);

        public BackgroundTaskManager()
        {
            _OwnerDispatcher = System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
            _WorkerThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(WorkerStart));
            _WorkerThread.Name = "BackgroundTaskManager:" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
            _WorkerThread.IsBackground = true;
            _WorkerThread.Start();

            _WorkerStarted.WaitOne();
        }

        public Boolean IsBusy
        {
            get { return _WorkerBusy; }
        }

        public System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher Dispatcher 
        {
            get {
                return _WorkerDispatcher;
            }
        }

        public System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher OwnerDispatcher
        {
            get
            {
                return _OwnerDispatcher;
            }
        }


        private void WorkerStart()
        {
            _WorkerDispatcher = System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
            _WorkerDispatcher.Hooks.DispatcherInactive += WorkDone;
            _WorkerDispatcher.Hooks.OperationPosted += WorkAdded;
            _WorkerStarted.Set();
            System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
        }

        private void WorkAdded(Object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherHookEventArgs e)
        {
            _WorkerBusy = true;
        }

        private void WorkDone(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _WorkerBusy = false;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_WorkerDispatcher != null)
            {
                _WorkerDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
                _WorkerDispatcher = null;
            }
        }

    }
}


// Useage (not tested)

private SSA.Utility.BackgroundTaskManager _background = new SSA.Utility.BackgroundTaskManager();

public void LongTaskAsync() 
{
  _background.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(LongTask), null);
}

public void LongTask() 
{
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000); // simulate a long task
   _background.OwnerDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<STATUSCLASS>(LongTaskUpdate), statusobject);
}

public void LongTaskUpdate(STATUSCLASS statusobject) {

}
```

Comment: This seems like a really complicated way creating a background task. I would use BackgroundWorker. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: I admit it is overkill for most things but I like that the syntax to use it is identical to the normal dispatcher and I like the priority feature.  I use it for a queue of work items instead of a single action.  BackgroundWorker does not have a built in feature for that.  The original question was about dispatcher in a new thread which this implements.

Comment: If you could separate our the essence of your answer and perhaps share an advices on useful additions, the answer would be much better. Thanks for sharing anyway and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. _Runner.Action is the problem. Some long-timed methods used in the Dispatcher block. But solution is "dont use the any thread not related to UI in the dispatcher"