# Accessing UI Control from BackgroundWorker Thread

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, udp

I have a button on my windows form that calls the RunWorkerAsync() method, this in turn performs an action which then updates a ListBox on the same form.

After the DoWork event has finished I assign the Result for the event (Which is a list), I process the RunWorkerCompleted() event and then perform the following code to update my Listbox

[image]

which calls this:

[image]

(Apologies, code formatting won't work)

Now when I run the application and press the refresh button the following exception appears:

[image]

How would I get around this?

Edit:

The exception is thrown on the folowing statement, this occurs in the DoWork method where I clear the contents to keep the list up to date;

**listBoxServers.Items.Clear();**

Comment: Is this WPF or Windows Forms? And on which line do you get this exception?

Comment: @decyclone I've updated my question with more information

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a snippet which I find very handy:

```
public static void ThreadSafe(Action action)
{
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
        new MethodInvoker(action));
}
```

You can pass it any delegate of `Action` type or simply a lambda like this:

```
ThreadSafe(() =>
{
    [your code here]
});
```

or

```
ThreadSafe(listBoxServers.Items.Clear);
```

Comment: Isn't this WPF?  Does WinForms support the Dispatcher?

Comment: `Dispatcher` is a WPF class but this code will work with WinForms.

Comment: For some reason Dispatcher isn't recognised by IntelliSense, I have the System.Threading statement included.

Comment: Make sure you have `WindowsBase.dll` referenced in your project. The namespace is `System.Windows.Threading`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx

Comment: Winforms has a mechanism already for handling this. There is no reason to add a reference to yet another DLL and then the overhead of creating a `Dispatcher` object. Just use the `Control.Invoke()` or `Control.BeginInvoke()` method, as recommended by the [_correct_ answer that was posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4429346)

Answer (score 13):

You may not call `Invoke` on the list box, but on the form. For WinForms applications I use something like:

```
...
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
{
    // Do stuff on ANY control on the form.
});
...
```

Depending on the .NET version, you may have to declare a delegate for `MethodInvoker` yourself as

```
public delegate void MethodInvoker();
```

However, you might also consider using the `ReportProgress` feature of the Background Worker. The respective event handler should be called in the context of the form's thread.

Answer (score 9):

What I've done is something like this every time you need to run something across threads:

```
listBoxServers.BeginInvoke(
    (Action)
    (() => listBoxServers.Items.Clear()));
```

Comment: Typical Lisp problem, there seems to be a paren missing.

Comment: Thanks Hans, i've added the missing paren.

Answer (score 1):

Background threads are not allowed to update the UI in Windows applications, so you have to revert the control back to the UI thread for the actual update.

Create a method that will call UpdateServerDetails on the main thread, like this:

```
private void DispatchServerDetails(List<ServerDetails> details)
{
  Action<List<ServerDetails>> action = UpdateServerDetails;
  Dispatcher.Invoke(action)
}
```

and then call `DispatchServerDetails` instead of `UpdateServerDetails`.

Some caveats:
-This works best in WPF applications, for WinForms, you'll need to jump through some hoops, or you can use [InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx)
-The UI update is still synchronous, so if UpdateServerDetails does a lot of work, it will block the UI thread (not your case, just to be on the safe side).

Comment: @Jamie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975087/wpf-dispatcher-and-running-it-in-background

Answer (score 1):

Using Invoke in a windows forms project can be a little tricky, there're some pitfalls that are documented but easy to miss.  I recommend using something like you'll find in this question:

[Is it appropriate to extend Control to provide consistently safe Invoke/BeginInvoke functionality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714666)

It handles cases where invoke is not required, is called from different threads, handle is or isn't created, etcetcetc.  It could be easily modified to be `SafeInvoke()` and `SafeBeginInvoke()` if you're not a fan of the bool parameter.

(Included here for your convenience:

```
/// Usage:
this.lblTimeDisplay.SafeInvoke(() => this.lblTimeDisplay.Text = this.task.Duration.ToString(), false);

// or 
string taskName = string.Empty;
this.txtTaskName.SafeInvoke(() => taskName = this.txtTaskName.Text, true);


/// <summary>
/// Execute a method on the control's owning thread.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="uiElement">The control that is being updated.</param>
/// <param name="updater">The method that updates uiElement.</param>
/// <param name="forceSynchronous">True to force synchronous execution of 
/// updater.  False to allow asynchronous execution if the call is marshalled
/// from a non-GUI thread.  If the method is called on the GUI thread,
/// execution is always synchronous.</param>
public static void SafeInvoke(this Control uiElement, Action updater, bool forceSynchronous)
{
    if (uiElement == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("uiElement");
    }

    if (uiElement.InvokeRequired)
    {
        if (forceSynchronous)
        {
            uiElement.Invoke((Action)delegate { SafeInvoke(uiElement, updater, forceSynchronous); });
        }
        else
        {
            uiElement.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate { SafeInvoke(uiElement, updater, forceSynchronous); });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!uiElement.IsHandleCreated)
        {
            // Do nothing if the handle isn't created already.  The user's responsible
            // for ensuring that the handle they give us exists.
            return;
        }

        if (uiElement.IsDisposed)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("Control is already disposed.");
        }

        updater();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out a simpler way without using Invoke:

```
int fakepercentage = -1;
//some loop here......if no loop exists, just change the value to something else
if (fakepercentage == -1)
{
    fakepercentage = -2;
}
else
{
    fakepercentage = -1;
}
backgroundworker1.ReportProgress(fakepercentage);
```

Then in backgroundworker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e):

```
if (e.ProgressPercentage < 0)
{
    //access your ui control safely here
}
```