# how to use a long running process in winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a background for my sms application.

I have created an application which needs to send messages continously.

When i use background.My application gets hanged i dont know why it is,

my code is

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   //mycode
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(
    object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    backgroundWorker1.RunworkAsync();
}
```

later i have tried this

```
public void Thread()
{
    Thread D = new Thread(BackgroundCode);
    D.Start();
}

public void BackgroundCode()
{
    for (int i5 = 1; i5 > 0; i5 += 1)
    {
       //mycode
    }

}
```

this two works fine for 2 or 3 min but after that it gets hang.

Please can anyone please help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: are you accessing UI controls in the thread!!

Comment: Does it pause and later continue? How long have you waited for the hang to release? If your code is very fast you could quickly run out of ints in your loop.

Comment: Your background code is an infinite loop?

Comment: it does not continue later it gets hanged permanently

Comment: @Robar Yes, because its not a background and i need to make a loop in it to run it until the app is closed

Comment: If you are accessing UI controls in your background code, you have to use the Dispatcher (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428817/accessing-ui-control-from-backgroundworker-thread-c-sharp)

Comment: are you accesing UI controls like textbox,button from the thread or background worker..
Calls to textbox or other controls should be made through UI thread and not from the backgroundworker or user-created-thread!!

Comment: yes there are textboxes , comboboxes in background

Comment: Then you have to use the Dispatcher

Comment: suppose my code is  foreach (string name in checkedlbdestinationnumber.CheckedItems)
                    {

Comment: how do i use the dipatcher in the middle

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4429009/333404

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   while(true)
   {
       //your sms code
       //call CancelAsync() here if you want to get out!!!!
   }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(
    object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   //donot include RunWorkerAsync() and CancelAsync() in this method!
}
```

Comment: Anirudha please wait while i check.

Comment: after it get hangs i am getting an error that is A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

Comment: @Arshiya your for loop is infinite and you will never come out of it!

Comment: my application is still hanging can any 1 please help me.

Answer (score 0):

[This is a bit of a long post](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/06/reporting-progress-from-tasks.html), but it seems to fit your problem quite well.

Basically, it shows how you can do this with a BackgroundWorker or the Task Parallel Library (TPL would be my suggestion)

For the TPL you create a ProgressReporter class that will be used in the class to pass messages back to the main thread, while continuing to run the task.

Also, your for loop will never end because it is saying to run while i5 is greater than 0. And, it starts at 1 and counts up, so it will never be less than or equal to zero. That will fix your hanging, but once you fix that, the progress reporter from the blog class should help with the rest.