# Why don't execute task in ContinueWith?

Tags: c#, winforms, task-parallel-library, task

I have async methods that returns an objects

```
public static IEnumerable<Users.User> GetUsers(IEnumerable<string> uids, Field fields)
{
    Task<ResponseApi<Users.User>>[] tasks;
    tasks = uids.Select(uid =>
    {
        var parameters = new NameValueCollection
        {
        {"uids", uid},
        {"fields", FieldsUtils.ConvertFieldsToString(fields)}
        };
        return GetUserResponseApi(parameters);
    }).ToArray();
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    foreach(Task<ResponseApi<Users.User>> task in tasks)
    {
        if(task.Result.Response != null)
        {
            yield return task.Result.Response;
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to update UI in other method,UI maybe don't update because method GetUserResponseApi don't return any value.

```
 public static Task<ResponseApi<Users.User>> GetUserResponseApi(NameValueCollection parameters)
    {
      return CallMethodApi("users.get", parameters, CallType.HTTPS)
            .ContinueWith(
            r =>
            {
//don't execute
                var responseApi = new ResponseApi<Users.User>();
                responseApi.Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Users.User>(r.Result["response"][0].ToString());
                return responseApi;

            });
    }

    private void BtnGetUsersClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        int max = 175028595;
        var uids = new List<string>();
        for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            uids.Add((random.Next(max) + 1).ToString());

        }
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                  {
                                      var users = VkontakteApi.GetUsers(uids, Field.Online);
                                      foreach(var user in users)
                                      {
                                          richTextBox1.Text += string.Format("ID:{0} online:{1}", user.uid,
                                                                             user.online);
                                      }
                                  }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, _uiContext);
    }
```

How to resolve problem with ContinueWith in `GetUserResponseApi`?

**UPDATE:**
I think that problem in method `GetUserResponseApi` because block ContinueWith doesn't execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Application.Current.Dispatcher` to dispatch calls to UI thread whenever you access UI objects.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
try
{
richTextBox1.Text += string.Format("ID:{0} online:{1}", user.uid, user.online);
}
catch
{
   //handle
}
), DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

Comment: Wow, I never knew about this! Will it work if it's in a separate/background thread/task?

Comment: Yep. Dispatcher was created especially for this purpose, to update UI from background threads.

Comment: Where is Current ? [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application_properties)

Comment: @Victor You didn't specify what UI library you're using, so invisible assumed you're using WPF.

Comment: Yep, I assumed this is WPF. But you could still use Dispatcher in WinForms. You need to reference WindowsBase library in your project. Same question was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4429009/166584

Comment: @invisible Why would you use `Dispatcher` in Winforms when you can use `Control.Invoke()`?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext.aspx):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
      var users = VkontakteApi.GetUsers(uids, Field.Online);
      foreach(var user in users)
      {
          richTextBox1.Text += string.Format("ID:{0} online:{1}", user.uid,
                                             user.online);
      }
  }, CancellationToken.None,
     TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: `GetUsers()` is the method that takes a long time, running it on the UI thread is a terrible idea.