# opening a window form from another form programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a Windows Forms application. I have a form. I want to open a **new form** at run time from the original form on a button click. And then close this **new form** (after 2,3 sec) programatically but from a thread other than gui main thread.

1. Can anybody guide me how to do it ?
2. Will the new form affect or hinder the things going on in the original main form ? (if yes than how to stop it ?)

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Why wait 2,3 seconds?

Comment: Did you try anything at all?

Comment: It is one of my favorite repeated question.....:)

Answer (score 54):

To open from with button click please add the following code in the button event handler

```
var m = new Form1();
m.Show();
```

Here Form1 is the name of the form which you want to open.

Also to close the current form, you may use

```
this.close();
```

Comment: what is Form1 ?

Comment: Form1 is the name of the form to open. If it is named something else, then use something else here.

Answer (score 14):

I would do it like this:

```
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.Show();
```

and to close current form I would use

`this.Hide();` instead of

```
this.close();
```

check out this [Youtube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/breakPointed)  link for easy start-up tutorials you might find it helpful if u are a beginner

Answer (score 9):

This is an old question, but answering for gathering knowledge.
We have an original form with a button to show the new form.

[image]

The code for the button click is below

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    New_Form new_Form = new New_Form();
    new_Form.Show();
}
```

Now when click is made, New Form is shown. Since, you want to hide after 2  seconds we are adding a onload event to the new form designer

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.OnPageLoad);
```

This **OnPageLoad** function runs when that form is loaded

In **NewForm.cs** ,

```
public partial class New_Form : Form
{
    private Timer formClosingTimer;

    private void OnPageLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        formClosingTimer = new Timer();  // Creating a new timer 
        formClosingTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(CloseForm); // Defining tick event to invoke after a time period
        formClosingTimer.Interval = 2000; // Time Interval in miliseconds
        formClosingTimer.Start(); // Starting a timer
    }
    private void CloseForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        formClosingTimer.Stop(); // Stoping timer. If we dont stop, function will be triggered in regular intervals
        this.Close(); // Closing the current form
    }
}
```

In this new form , a timer is used to invoke a method which closes that form.

Here is the new form which automatically closes after 2 seconds, we will be able operate on both the forms where no interference between those two forms.

[image]

For your knowledge,

`form.close()` will free the memory and we can never interact with that form again
`form.hide()` will just hide the form, where the code part can still run

For more details about timer refer this link, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 2):

This might also help:

```
void ButtQuitClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    QuitWin form = new QuitWin();
    form.Show();
}
```

Change **ButtQuit** to your button name and also change **QuitWin** to the name of the form that you made.

**When the button is clicked it will open another window, you will need to make another form and a button on your main form for it to work.**

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use Dispatcher to perform graphical operation from a thread other then UI thread. I don't think that this will affect behavior of the main form. This may help you :
[Accessing UI Control from BackgroundWorker Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428817/accessing-ui-control-from-backgroundworker-thread-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

```
private void btnchangerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();  //current form will hide
        Form1 fm = new Form1(); //another form will open
        fm.Show();


    }
```

on click btn current form will hide and new form will open