# C# Add Form to running application

Tags: c#, forms, windows

Simple question:

I used `Application.Run` to start my application because I need it this way.

Now I want to add a form later in the code. But it doesn't open the form if I use `new Form1`. Instead it runs everything else in the constructor of the class Form1. So somehow it ignores to open the form.

Comment: You mean you want to call the opened Form1?

Comment: you also have to show it, `(new Form1()).Show();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [opening a window form from another form programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041382/opening-a-window-form-from-another-form-programmatically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `new`ing up a form makes it exist in memory but does not display anything.

You have to show it:

```
// create instance of Form1, does not show it
var myForm = new Form1();
// show the form.
myForm.Show();
```

see [msdn documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show(v=vs.110).aspx)