# Use progress bar to read data from excel file using c#

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I am having problems in using progress bar while I he app reads and gets data from excel sheet

This is what I want to do-:

- My application reads data from cells of various excel sheets in a workbook
- Once the data is read, a message box is shown to user which reads "File read successfully"
- I need to run a progress bar in the form while the data is being read from the file and it need to show % completion once before the message box pops up

This is what I did -:

- I added a background worker and a progress bar
- this is snippet of code which calls Run worker, RunWorkerAsync is called when the button is clicked and file to read is selected.

  ```
  // Start the BackgroundWorker.
          fileReadingbackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
  ```
- A snippet that reports progress

  ```
  int percentProcessFile =1;
  for (int i = 1; i <= countSheets; i++)
  {
      readSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(i);

      for (int row = 2; row <= 100; row++)
      {
          if (readSheet.Cells[1][row].Text.ToString() != "")
          {
              for (int column = 1; column <= 15; column++)
              {
                  String Key = readSheet.Cells[1][row].Text.ToString();
                  String readCaptionCell = readSheet.Cells[column][1].Text.ToString();
                  String readCurrentCell = readSheet.Cells[column][row].Text.ToString();
                  if (readSheet.Name == "ISMB")
                        ISMBSections.Add(Key, readCaptionCell, readCurrentCell);
                  else if (readSheet.Name == "ISMC")
                        ISMCSections.Add(Key, readCaptionCell, readCurrentCell);
               }                        
         }
         else
         {
             break;
         }
         precentProgressFile++;
         fileReadingbackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(precentProgressFile);
     }   
  }
  ```

The line `fileReadingbackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(precentProgressFile);` throws an exception

- I have added the following lines as well

  ```
  private void fileReadingbackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
  {
      for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
      {
          // Wait 100 milliseconds.
          Thread.Sleep(100);
          // Report progress.
          fileReadingbackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(j);

      }
  }

  private void fileReadingbackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      fileReadingProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
  }
  ```

The line `fileReadingbackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(precentProgressFile);` in the second snippet throws an exception

I am unable to understand what goes wrong here.
I am using Visual Studio 12.0 and .Net 4.0
Please ask if you have any questions

Not a duplicate of [Accessing UI Control from BackgroundWorker Thread - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428817/accessing-ui-control-from-backgroundworker-thread-c-sharp) 
reason for this is I have not used DispatcherInvoke anywhere.

Comment: Please add the message of the exception. Exceptions are messages to the developer, what exactly went wrong. Your program is trying to tell you, but you don't listen (yet).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing UI Control from BackgroundWorker Thread - C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428817/accessing-ui-control-from-backgroundworker-thread-c-sharp)

Comment: Not a duplicate of Accessing UI Control from BackgroundWorker Thread - C# reason for this is I have not used DispatcherInvoke anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The BackgroundWorker has a property called `WorkerReportsProgress` which needs to be set to true in order to report the progress.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention but I did that

Comment: @vin then I really need atleast the type of the Exception