# Adding many items to listbox freezes UI

Tags: c#, buffer, getfiles

I am making a program which finds duplicate files in a directory, but when the directory it is searching has too many of those files it will crash the application.
I was wondering if there is a way to buffer the amount of files it grabs. 
Here is the code that does the thing I am explaining:

```
string[] filePathsb = Directory.GetFiles(
      @"" + Dirfind, "*" + filetyperest, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

for (int i = 0; i < filePathsb.Length; i++)
   {

     ListBoxItem itm = new ListBoxItem();

     try
     {
        List<TodoItem> items = new List<TodoItem>();

        filelistboxitem.Items.Add(new TodoItem() { Title = "" + filePathsb[i], Deletea = "" + i });
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error occurance: " + ex);
     }

}
```

Just a note: this works fine when there are about < 50 files.

Comment: Define "crash the application".  Adding 50 items, or even 200, to a listbox should not cause problems.  Adding thousands of items to a listbox can be a problem (in addition to being a poor user experience).  Do you get an exception (details?), does the program lock up, or what exactly?

Comment: I do not get any exception from what I think is it happens when i do this:                                                            'string[] filePathsb = Directory.GetFiles(@"" + Dirfind, "*" + filetyperest, SearchOption.AllDirectories);'

Comment: so the crash just makes the window freeze when I run the function

Comment: Have you considered using a different Thread for the Directory.GetFiles call?

Comment: i agree with Eric... please describe the "crash" as it happens. i built my own FileSync C# app, and i once ran it against a dir that had something like 7000 files in it and it didn't crash anything. Now it did freeze the app until all the files were read, so i switched to threading to keep the UI responsive...

Comment: the program just literally locks up I will show you a video gif in a sec

Comment: @andrew196: Now many files were loaded for the gif you are going to add?

Comment: my computer isnt even slow I have got an i7 processor

Comment: Have you tried debugging? This is a really simple for loop, it shouldn't be happening.

Comment: ah my bad I had it open in the background it just took about 1.5 minutes to load all of the files. But I wouldnt have thought it world have taken that long. @EricJ. There were about 1000+ files

Comment: I've updated title of your post based on your comments - please verify if changte is accurate/update. Please *don't* use "crashes" as "does not update UI/freezes" - "crash" for most readers means "throws unhanded exception".

Comment: @andrew196: Not unexpected.  Have a look at my answers for two solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinForms can become quite slow and unresponsive if you add many items to a ListBox.  This is particularly true if, as in your example, you do the adding from the UI thread.  The UI will freeze up until the last item is added.

**What can I do?**

A simple improvement is to call

```
SuspendLayout();
```

before your loop starts, and

```
ResumeLayout();
```

after the loop completes.  That will reduce the cost of updating the listbox, so the whole thing completes faster.

**How Can I Prevent Locking the UI Entirely?**

You can use threading to update the list in the background.  For WinForms, [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker) is commonly used.  Note that you cannot directly update the UI from the BackgroundWorker, as they run on different threads.  The usual event mechanism `ReportProgress` does not apply in this situation, since you want to continually update the UI until all files are loaded.  Instead, you can use the approach outlined here:

[Accessing UI Control from BackgroundWorker Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428817/accessing-ui-control-from-backgroundworker-thread-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the Backgroundworker thread for finding files.your UI will not freeze then and file finding logic will run in 'background'

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share my experience when using multi-thread MFC application.
Do not use Wait Functions in the main thread which is handling the message loop.
Otherwise it will enter a infinite dead loop.