# Avoiding Cross-Thread Operations

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I want to access selections from a listbox on my GUI from my backgroundworker.  Without any additional changes trying to do such throws this error

```
Cross-thread Operation Not Valid: Control '_ListBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on
```

The option I saw to avoid this is to use `Invoke` by the following syntax, but is this `.Net 4` (or higher) acceptable?

```
var selectedItems = (IList)this.Invoke(new Func<IList>(() => Listbox1.SelectedItems.Cast<object>().ToList()));
```

For a clearer picture this is how I want to access listbox items from my backgroundworker

```
namespace clown
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form1
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      ListBox1.Items.Add("Firefly");
      ListBox1.Items.Add("Hellfire");
    }

    private void btn1234_Click()
    {
      backgroundworker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundworker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
      //Long Running Process taking place here 
      //then we hit this
      if (ListBox1.SelectedItems.Contains("Firefly")) { //take this course }
      if (ListBox1.SelectedItems.Contains("Hellfire)) { //take this course }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by .Net 4 acceptable? Do mean like standards wise or compile wise?

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: What does “to access selections” mean? And what API are you using? ASP.NET? WinForms? WPF? Metro (or whatever Microsoft is calling it this week)?

Comment: @Alex & Josh L.- it works, issue free.  Just wasn't sure if it was "Acceptable" to do such.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing UI Control from BackgroundWorker Thread - C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428817/accessing-ui-control-from-backgroundworker-thread-c-sharp)

Comment: @John Very likely a duplicate question but all the answers in your link are all based on the incorrect premise that `Invoke` should be used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Invoke` in the `Backgroundworker's` `DoWork` event handler is frowned upon by Microsoft.  You should consider using the `Backgroundworker's` `ProgressChanged` or `RunWorkerCompleted` events instead.

See [MSDN Help Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx).

See the first Note for this text:

> You must be careful not to manipulate any user-interface objects in
>   your DoWork event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface
>   through the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events.

If you actually posted more code, a fuller answer may be given.

**Edit 1: More Code**

Since the OP updated his post to contain more code, I have done the same.

```
   private void btn1234_Click()
   {
        var items = ListBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<string>();
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(items);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
        var items = (IEnumerable<string>)e.Argument;
        //Long Running Process taking place here  then we hit this
        if (items.Contains("Firefly")) { /* take this course */ }
        if (items.Contains("Hellfire")) { /* take this course */ }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for that!  I have updated my initial post to give a cleaner picture of what I am attempting to achieve.

Comment: I agree with you. I'd consider providing the worker with all the info it needed in the click method - and status updates go via the methods you described

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon how would I pass the selected items into the backgroundworker?

Comment: @user2676140 I've provided an example on how to pass items.  But I strongly suggest you invest more time in reading the MSDN help and reviewing their examples.

Comment: @Rick Davin: Thanks for adding the parameter passing ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is "acceptable", but it's not a good practice nowadays. BackgroundWorker is considered obsolete and one should use Tasks with async/await instead.

Here is an example of how I would implement a method to execute something on another thread, keep the UI responsive and update the UI after execution is finished (with WPF and the MVVM pattern):

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...

    public string PathInfo { ... } // raises INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event from the setter
    public RelayCommand ProcessPathsCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        ProcessPathsCommand = new RelayCommand(ProcessPaths);
    }

    public async void ProcessPaths()
    {
        // disable the command, which will lead to disabling a button bound to the command
        ProcessPathsCommand.IsEnabled = false;

        try
        {
            string result = null;
            // run processing on another thread
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // emulate hard-work
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                result = "Here are the results: bla bla bla";
            });

            // update the property on the view model, which will lead to updating a textblock bound to this property                
            // thanks to the "await" keyword, this line of code will be executed only when the task finishes
            // and it will be executed on UI thread
            PathInfo = result;
        }
        finally
        {
            ProcessPathsCommand.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Feel free to let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I am using a winforms project would the same principle be applicable as with WPF?

Comment: Well, I think MVVM is not very popular among WinForms developers, because when MVVM became popular WinForms was already out for several years and so there are a lot of WinForms developers who are used to their old approach.
But yes, the same principle can be applicable to WinForms.